# Couldn't install winexe-1.00, Python not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

When I was installing winexe 1.00, after [winexe-1.00/source4/]./configure I got the following message:

```
checking for python2.6... /usr/local/bin/python2.6
checking for python2.6-config... /usr/local/bin/python2.6-config
checking working python module support... no
configure: error: Python not found. Please install Python 2.x and its development headers/libraries.
```

But I installed both Python 2.6 and 2.7. I couldn't find what's the problem.

Comment: The error message specifically mentions headers. Did you also install python2.6-dev (assuming Debian / Ubuntu)?

Comment: Thanks, when use this to install Python2.6-dev, it tells : E: Unable to locate package python2.6-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python2.6-dev

Comment: Tag this question with your operating system name.

Comment: It's there.  http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python2.6-dev

Answer (score 1):

just install python via yum or apt:

```
apt-get install python-all-dev
```

Comment: More detail would improve this.

Comment: Why is this down-voted? It was exactly what I needed. -- +1